# Uno Platform camera preview control

Tags: uno-platform

How can I add an camera preview in a uno XAML Page?

Could be like this example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/simple-camera-preview-access

But the CameraCapture.InitializeAsyn is not implemented on Uno.
When it runs the following exception is thrown:

> System.NotImplementedException: The member IAsyncAction
> MediaCapture.InitializeAsync() is not implemented in Uno.

If is possible to use native android code, this sample do what I need.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android50-camera2basic/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you have at least two ways for doing something similar:

You can use the following, with native android intents, that you'll need to make conditional with `__ANDROID__`:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
...

    BaseActivity.Current.ActivityResult += Current_ActivityResult;
}

private void Current_ActivityResult(object sender, BaseActivity.ActivityResultEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Data != null)
   {
      var bitmap = (Bitmap)e.Data.Extras.Get("data");

      image.Source = bitmap;
   }
   else
   {
      image.Source = null;
   }
}

public void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
   BaseActivity.Current.StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

or using the `CameraCaptureUI` class:

```cs
{
    try
    {
        var captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
        captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
        captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(200, 200);

        var photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

        if (photo == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(photo.Path));
            image.Source = source;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

You can find the full examples for [CameraCaptureUI](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Samples/tree/master/UI/CameraCaptureUI/CameraCaptureUISample/CameraCaptureUISample.Shared), and [native android](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Samples/blob/master/UI/AndroidCustomCamera/AndroidCustomCamera/AndroidCustomCamera.Shared).

Other types of camera capture are currently not implemented (as of Uno 3.0), and you'll need to go through native APIs to use them.

Comment: Those examples help to get the image, but is necessary to have a camera preview inside the app. Do you know anything about preview? Even a custom renderer strategy is valid for us. Thanks!

Comment: This Xamarin Forms sample is what I need to do https://github.com/UNIT-23/Xam-Android-Camera2-Sample